# Sending an email from within iOS web app without closing web app and opening mail

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, email, mailto

Currently when I send a mail message from within an iOS web app (fullscreen from home screen) the web app closes and the mail app opens.

The same thing happens in Color Mail: http://www.apple.com/webapps/productivity/colormail.html. When you send a mail message you are kicked out of the web app.

Is there a way to send a mail message and remain inside the fullscreen web app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send an email without using the Apple Mail client (which is basically what you're asking) you'll need to use a web service that support sending email in response to a request.

For example, Amazon's Simple Email Service lets you send email in response to an API query.

However, if what you're after is sending an email message *from the user's own account* then you unfortunately must exit the app and go into Apple Mail - in much the same way that a `mailto:` link would do if you used it on a website.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: IF you were a native app, what you'd be after is the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). It allows you to bring up a standard mail compose interface right within your app.

HOWEVER, since you're not, you're going to have to build your own form interface, and then take the form submission on the web app and send the mail from there.

(Sorry. Didn't read.)

Comment: Thanks for your responses; Dan Ray, do you have any links to good resources on building the form interface? My issue is I'm not very familiar with php - which I'm pretty sure is necessary.